# AH01797: client denied by server configuration: <directory_name>/update/cron.php14,19,33,45

Tags: magento2, configuration

I was just changing my magento2 mode from developer to production,
And it resulted in blank webpage on the application URL.
In my webserver logs I have found:
**AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /update/cron.php14,19,33,45**.